# Intel MKL failes to load. Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_core.dylib

Tags: python, tensorflow, fatal-error, intel-mkl

I tried to set up a file to write an AI with PyCharm. 
The tutorial I'm using: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujTCoH21GlA

When I run the code:

```
$ import tensorflow
```

Then I get the error:

```
$ Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_core.dylib.
```

Has someone an idea how I can fix this problem?

I've tried nearly everything​ what I found on the internet, but nothing helped to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to follow the below steps from your command prompt.

Create a conda environment using the command:

```
conda create -n my_env python=3.6
```

Activate the environment:

```
activate my_env
```

Install tensorflow as:

```
conda install tensorflow-mkl
```

In pycharm, from the settings, add the pythonw.exe from the environment 'my_env' to the project interpreter (as shown in the video you had provided).

I had tried with a sample test file and it worked for me.

Hope this helps.